# Allowing any keyboard to input for passwords

Tags: keyboard, password, language

I use 3 keyboard layouts: Dvorak-Sougou (Chinese), Dvorak-Kana (Japanese), and Dvorak (English). Whenever I input a password, it always returns me to the EN-Dvorak layout.

The problem is two-fold:

1) I want to remove my plain Dvorak keyboard, but can't because mac recognizes it as the only ASCII keyboard in use, because all my other keyboards are technically "input methods", not "keyboard layouts". This is even though my chinese keyboard inputs all the same characters regular dvorak does just fine, making the first one redundant.

**How can I fix this so that I can delete my plain Dvorak keyboard from my list of keyboards in use?**

2) I want to allow my Chinese Dvorak keyboard to input passwords. Currently, my computer always reverts to English when I type passwords. The two input all the same characters, but my chinese dvorak keyboard grays out for passwords, and I can't select it to input characters into a password field.

**How can I allow a keyboard to be used for password input?**

An important limitation in my opinion is the classification of my other two keyboards as "input methods" rather than keyboard layouts. That is to say, they occupy a different folder, and use the layouts of other keyboards. But, to me as a user, this doesn't make them less useful -- rather the opposite. They also aren't reliant on dvorak being on my list of used keyboards, so I don't see why removing it should have an effect on their usage.

Comment: Just wondering how did you add all the keyboards in first place?

Comment: My Japanese one is the Japanese one native to Mac, and I downloaded sougou from the Internet (pinyin.sougou.com)

Comment: Thank you for the info, sorry I can not help since I have no idea what are you talking about. I only use standard Mac keyboard input sources like German, English and the Unicode Hex Input.